# Spring Integration and REST Gateway

Tags: spring-integration

Question is about feature/capability. Trying to understand if Spring Integration can be used to build a Gateway for RESTful web services. Essentially, looking to build a proxy/gateway layer that would intercept all calls to back end REST services and add security, rules such as OAUTH, Throttling etc. I have reviewed apache synapse, wso2 API Manager and looking to build similar service using Spring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; starting with Spring Integration 3.0 (current version is 4.0.2), you can give an http inbound-gateway multiple paths (`foo/{bar}`, `/baz/{qux}`) etc. In previous versions you would need a separate gateway for each URL, which would be impractical for a large service.

Depending on the complexity, you might want to consider implementing the restful front-end using [Spring MVC's ReST support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) directly and interfacing with a back-end Spring Integration flow using a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) as necessary.

The [spring-security-oauth project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) is available for oauth.

EDIT: There is also a [rest-http sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/rest-http).

Comment: I was trying to find a sample from the repository but could not find one I could use. Also, I already have oauth implemented using spring security and need to hook into the gateway. Any pointers would help.

Comment: We don't currently have a ReST sample, but it should be as simple as changing the [http sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/http), changing the `path` to `path=/receivegateway/foo/{bar},/receivegateway/baz/{qux}` etc. The http gateway runs inside Spring MVC (it simply sets up request mappings from the path for the `DispatcherServlet`) so applying the security layer should be identical to any Spring MVC application.

Comment: Ran the http sample and it appears that it would accept the input and echo it with additional text. However, what I am looking for is to forward the input to an external REST service and return the response to the client.

Comment: Right - you would need to configure an outbound gateway instead of just building the reply internally... `inbound-gateway -> outbound-gateway`.

Comment: Is there a sample that I could use to learn on how to pass inbound data to outbound data.

Comment: The client side of that same sample has an outbound gateway (`src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/http-outbound-config.xml`). Simply copy the outbound gateway from there to the servlet-config.xml and remove the service activator - change the outbound gateway's requestChannel to `receiveChannel`. Also, read up on the http support... http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I need to figure out how to make it dynamic. For example, GET method for /user/{id} I need to pass {id} variable to back end REST service. This way it would be more dynamic and usable.

Comment: Got it working. Here is the configuration for reference. `code` <int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel"
  path="/user/{id}" supported-methods="GET" 
  payload-expression="#pathVariables.id"/>

 <int:channel id="receiveChannel" />  
 
 <int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

 <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel" 
  url="http://localhost:8081/api/user/{id}"
  http-method="GET"
  expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
  <int-http:uri-variable name="id" expression="payload"/>
 </int-http:outbound-gateway> `code`

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention we also have a rest-http sample (edited my answer).

Comment: I looked at it. But, it kinda offers a REST interface for a service. My requirements was to create a "proxy" like service that would authenticate and throttle before forwarding to back end REST service which is already built and secured with OAUTH. Like to offload OAUTH to proxy layer. Essentially, I am looking to build a API manager.

Comment: Sure no problem; I just wanted to be sure others that stumble across this question will see it.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I am reviewing Poller on achieving throttling like N number of requests in X amount of time (in cluster eventually). Am I in the right direction? Should I open another thread?

Comment: Yes; another question would be appropriate.

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046737/spring-integration-http-request-throttling