# Spring Integration HTTP request throttling

Tags: spring-integration

Looking to implement http request throttle limits and wondering if Poller is the option or should Interceptor be used? The idea is have a rule of "X number of requests/operations in Y amount of time" and it should work across the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do to the throttled caller; throw an exception (after some timeout) or wait forever. Using a queue channel after the gateway (with a limit and a `send-timeout` on the gateway) would work, and throw an exception if the time exceeded; setting the timeout to -1 (default) would block forever.

You can catch the exception via an `error-channel` on the gateway and return a friendly "too busy" reply (if you timeout).

An interceptor could probably be crafted to be more sophisticated - a rate limit Vs. a simple queue limit.